# D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: android, android-camera, android-manifest, android-fileprovider

i am using https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo this scan library in my project.

when i capture image i am getting `D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'` in console and The captured image not sets to imageview in ***Android P***.

also when i am testing same app in ***Android Q*** i am getting below error.

`2020-02-05 11:32:23.668 9270-9270/? E/ReviewScreenImpl: onClickOKButton() - Fail to decode captured picture`

Can someone please help on above issues.

Comment: have you created an issue for this on their github ?

Comment: yes i have created issue on github but before also i have created 2,3 issues there and not got any response.

Comment: just making sure, it's usually a good idea to make an issue on github

Comment: any solution to this ?

Comment: I get this error when using new activity result api for camera result

Comment: I also had the same problem when using Activity Result API for camera result. Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73892409/4866667

This error message ('unimplemented') occurred because the image file was empty (0 bytes) in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and it seems there is a bug in getResources not in library you used because I don`t use it. but, you can use ResourcesCompat instead, like this:

```
val myLogo = (ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(this.resources, R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp, null) as VectorDrawable).toBitmap()
```

or

```
val myLogo = (ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(this.resources, R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp, null) as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
```

depend on your drawable type(vector or image).

be aware that this will only run on API > 22.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have generated the image Uri which you will be sending with Intent to the camera app with the FileProvider.

The image uri where the camera app will save the picture before returning Activity.RESULT_OK should be generated with FileProvider like this

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        context.getString(R.string.file_sharing_authority),
        File(filePath)
```

For more information about how to share our file to other apps (like the camera app) to be read or written into, see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Answer (score -1):

Please pass the image byte string, instead of passing a simple string, into your decoder BitmapFactory.decodeStream method.

Comment: Can you provide code ?

Answer (score -1):

This bug originates from Android Studio emulator and probably has nothing to do with the API/library you choose, whether in native Android or Flutter. I had this problem once in a while, where it only took place in emulator. All network/online pictures can't be displayed on app and above error messages were shown all over the place. My app ran fine on my USB connected phone though.

Updating/redownloading the image for the emulator fixed the issue.